# statistics from models created

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to provide data to a plotting script jqplot of the amounts of clicks on a certain model

I have the main model: Listing has_many clicks
each click has a datestamp
how can I get a count of clicks created for each day in a date range?

Answer (score 0):

```
date_from = Date.parse '2010-06-01'
date_to = Date.parse '2010-07-01'
click_counts = (date_from..date_to).map{|date|
  [date, Click.count(:conditions => {:date_stamp => date})]
}
```

will return an array of `[date, count]` pairs for a given period. However, this will issue a database query for each day in the date range.

One common solution to solve such queries is to create a database table filled with all dates (say, for previous and next 10 years from now), and then perform a `JOIN`, similar to:

```
SELECT d.date, COUNT(c.date_stamp)
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN clicks c ON d.date = c.date_stamp
GROUP BY d.date
```

which will return all the click counts in a single query.

Or, as a third solution, you can get click counts for existing dates:

```
Click.find(:all,
  :select => "date_stamp, count(*) as count",
  :group => 'date_stamp',
  :conditions => ["date_stamp >= ? and date_stamp < ?", date_from, date_to])
```

and add "empty" days in Ruby.

Answer (score -1):

```
def number_of_clicks
    start_date = Date.strptime(params[:start_date],"%d/%m/%Y")
    end_date = Date.strptime(params[:end_date],"%d/%m/%Y") 
    options = {conditions = ["date_stamp > ? and date_stamp < ?", start_date, end_date}
    Listing.find(:all, options).size
 end
```

Comment: I think OP wants number of clicks per each day in the range. Also, performing `find` and then `size` is sub-optimal, as all the data needs to be transferred to the application and counted there, opposed to counting done by DB using `count` method.